# Upload many single files in many group with Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload

I'm doing project on angular 2 that upload many single file( many tag ( input type = "file" ), not (input type="file" multiple>) in many groups by call API.

Could you show me the good solution to upload those files in this case?

Comment: simple file upload will work what do you want to show

Comment: I wrote an answer to your similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/47989347/4389078